# Accessing directory with numbers spaces and - character through terminal

Tags: terminal

I am trying to enter a sub directory named **04 - Object Methods** using the cd command in my terminal and get the following response **cd: too many arguments** If I cd into a sub directory names Images then there is no issue. This is probably super basic, but I could not find the right words to feed google to get an answer.

I guess if I renamed the directory without the numbers and the spaces and dash it would work, but I want to know if there is a way keeping the directory name as it is?

Comment: cd "04 - Object Methods"

Comment: Thank you for replying and giving me the information that I was searching for. It seems cumbersome to add quotes "" but then again, I am sure that there is a good reason to have to do this!